# Issue with passing php variable to jquery modal

Tags: php, jquery

I don't know if this matters, but I am using the Remodal plugin to create modal(s). I am truly sorry if this is a repeated question, but I have been trying to figure this out for about three days now. All the posts that I found on stackoverflow don't solve the issue that I am having.

What I am trying to accomplish is... I have a table with user info in it. I am trying to pass an the id for the link, for the modal, that was pressed. Okay I was able to retrieve the id inside the modal, but it is only giving the first id that is being fed by a while loop. I dont know if it is simply because Remodal doesn't support multiple modal windows....

or ...

```
<a href="#" data-remodal-target="modal">Hub</a>
```

if the specific attribute value, I am talking about data-remodal-target as shown above, in the link that calls the modal needs to unique. I tried changing that attribute value and the modal wouldnt open so it cannot be changed unless the jquery is changed.

```js
//I believe this is how the modal pops open and close
//All the code above this block is creating the plugins I think
$(document).ready(function() {

    // data-remodal-target opens a modal window with the special Id
    $(document).on('click', '[data-' + PLUGIN_NAME + '-target]', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var elem = e.currentTarget;
      var id = elem.getAttribute('data-' + PLUGIN_NAME + '-target');
      var $target = $('[data-' + PLUGIN_NAME + '-id="' + id + '"]');

      $[PLUGIN_NAME].lookup[$target.data(PLUGIN_NAME)].open();
    });

    // Auto initialization of modal windows
    // They should have the 'remodal' class attribute
    // Also you can write the `data-remodal-options` attribute to pass params into the modal
    $(document).find('.' + NAMESPACE).each(function(i, container) {
      var $container = $(container);
      var options = $container.data(PLUGIN_NAME + '-options');

      if (!options) {
        options = {};
      } else if (typeof options === 'string' || options instanceof String) {
        options = parseOptions(options);
      }

      $container[PLUGIN_NAME](options);
    });

    // Handles the keydown event
    $(document).on('keydown.' + NAMESPACE, function(e) {
      if (current && current.settings.closeOnEscape && current.state === STATES.OPENED && e.keyCode === 27) {
        current.close();
      }
    });

    // Handles the hashchange event
    $(window).on('hashchange.' + NAMESPACE, handleHashChangeEvent);
  });
});
```

```html
<!--link to call modal-->
<a href="#" data-remodal-target="modal">Hub</a>

<!--How I am grabbing the id as of now-->
<script>var id = document.getElementById("user_id").innerHTML;</script>

<!--modal--> 
<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal">
<button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close" aria-label="Close"></button>
 <div class="content">
  <script>document.write(id)</script>
  <h2 id="modal1Title">Remodal</h2>
  <div><button onclick="alert(id);">CLick me</button></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Edit: The end goal is to be able to grab the correct id and do stuff with it so that I can change that row that matches that id in the database. I dont know if it matters, but I got all the code broken up into templates. Also the loop is populating a link for each user.

Edit 2: Thanks for trying guys. I am gonna chalk this up to not being possible till I gain more knowledge on how to do such things. Sorry for the waste of time.

Comment: Your question is totally unclear to me. Rather put actual and minimal code to reproduce the problem instead of lot of writings.

Comment: What you need? Some dynamic modals? Do you need urls with a unique id or a personalized url with your php variables?

Comment: Please give me your some sample code that you integrate.

Comment: i think you want to call same modal from "more than one" links but id is different. is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your `PHP variable` into specific `input` fields or variable value assign to any `class` or `id`. 
Then after you can get their value by using `jQuery` by their name of `class` or `id`.

like :- `<span class='phpvar' id='<?php $x=10; ?>'></span>`

Get value form model.

```
alert($('.phpvar').attr('id'));
```

I hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
var jsVar = "<?php echo $varPHP; ?>"; // passing php variable to JavaScript
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it here is what you probably should be doing:

```
<?php foreach ($tableentries as $entry) : ?>
    <a href="#some<?php echo $entry['id']?>"/>
    <div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="some<?php echo $entry['id']?>">
        do stuff with that modal
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```